# Is it bad to access a single file with multiple NSFileHandle's? - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function which is called when data is received from a network connection. I am appending this data in a file inside a serialized dispatch queue. I had a NSFileHandle(named "file" here) object, whose scope is such that it is pointing to another file before my dispatch runs and also the file was being closed elsewhere. So I created a new NSFileHandle(named "_file" here) for my dispatch closure like this -

```
if (autoDownloadFileWrite == nil) {
        autoDownloadFileWrite = dispatch_queue_create("com.myqueue.autodownfilewrite", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
}

char Path[MAXPATHLEN];
//getting file path
if (file && fcntl([file fileDescriptor], F_GETPATH, Path) != -1)
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:Path]);

//creating new file handle from file path
NSFileHandle* _file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:Path]];

//writing into file in dispatch
dispatch_async(autoDownloadFileWrite, ^{
    if (_file) {
        [_file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
        [_file writeData:data];
});
```

Is it good to create multiple NSFileHandle for a single file?
Also I am not closing the file, is that bad?

If my question belongs to codereview.stack... just comment, I will add it there.

Comment: Your `if` doesn't have `{}`s that code won't compile as written, btw.   It also doesn't make sense;  `if (_file)` will cause `[nil writeData:data]` which does nothing.

Comment: I might have missed that, apologies, I will add it...

Comment: @bbum I edited, I think the code is more descriptive now :)

Comment: I'd highly recommend you encapsulate the file I/O into a single object and, within that, you have a single NSFileHandle to talk to any one file.   That'll be more sane to manage and easier to refactor over time.